Properly getting access to Templater object in an Obsidian QuckAdd plugin user script
I am creating a user script for use in a QuickAdd plugin Macro in Obsidian. The Macro has a single step and simply runs the user script (JavaScript that uses the CommonJS standard). One of the steps in the user script is to create a new note in Obsidian with a Templater template. The problem I'm having is the script cannot access the templater.current_functions_object unless I manually create a new note with a Templater template first. I am guessing it gets loaded into memory after it is manually executed one time. I would like to run my Macro and have it automatically create the new note with a Templater template without the need for the manual step if possible.
Q: Is there a way to make sure the templater.current functions_object is avaiable in the user script without a need to manually create a new note with a Templater template first?
I created a simple test script below help figure this out.
When I run a test Macro with the following user script, I get 'Unable to access the tp current functions object.' with a fresh launch of Obsidian. If I manually create a new note in Obsidian with a Templater template, run the test Macro again, then it works and I get 'Found the tp current functions object!'. I'm attempting to run this without requiring the manual step.
Is there an elegant way to access the first property of an object...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
